# Populate the data in a list view based on api response in xamarin

Tags: listview, xamarin

`On click of a button, i am adding an entry and a remove icon. Based on api response i want to get the list of vehicles and further addition deletion and update process

I have written code , but while displaying api response in vehicles, i am not able to get the correct data in CollectionsList after for loop. I am able to display api response for vehicles one by one but while deletion correct data is not getting deleted

**XAML**

```
  <StackLayout x:Name="vehicleListLayout" Margin="40,0">
    <ListView x:Name="MyList" SeparatorVisibility="None" 
    HasUnevenRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionsList}"
              Footer="">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                   <Grid Margin="0" RowSpacing="0">
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                           <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/> 
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <Entry
                           Text="{Binding VehicleNumber1}" 
          WidthRequest="180"
                           Margin="5" VerticalOptions="Start"/>
                      <ImageButton Margin="5" Command="{Binding 
       Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand, Source={x:Reference 
         MyList}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}" 
      Grid.Column="1" Source="baseline_remove_black_24"
                                    HorizontalOptions="Start" 
       HeightRequest="20" WidthRequest="25"/>

                   </Grid>
               </ViewCell>
           </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
       </ListView>
      </StackLayout>
```

**View Model Class**

```
 namespace DriverTracker.ViewModels
  {
   public class ProfileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
    public ProfileData profileData;
    public ProfileData ProfileData { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Vehicles> _CollectionsList;

    public ObservableCollection<Vehicles> CollectionsList
    {
        get { return _CollectionsList; }
        set
        {
            _CollectionsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string name;
   

    public string ProfileName
    {
        get => name;

        set
        {
            if (name == value)
                return;
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand { get; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }

    public ProfileViewModel()
    {
        CollectionsList = new ObservableCollection<Vehicles>();
            
        loadProfileData();

        AddCommand = new Command(AddItems);

        DeleteCommand = new Command(OnDeleteTapped);

        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSaveTapped);

    }

    async void loadProfileData()
    {
        try
        {
            profileData = await 
        ProfileManager.GetProfileDataAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WebService:GetEventsDataAsync:Failed 
        to 
        get events");
        }
        if (profileData == null) {
            profileData = new ProfileData();

        }
        
        //Loads Profile Data

        ProfileName = profileData.name;
       
        Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
        if (profileData.vehicles != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<profileData.vehicles.Count; i++)
            {
                vehicles.VehicleNumber1 = profileData.vehicles[i];
                CollectionsList.Add(vehicles);
            }
            
        }
        
        Id = profileData.Id;

        OnPropertyChanged("ProfileData");
       }

       private void AddItems(object obj)
       {
        Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
        CollectionsList.Insert(0, vehicles);
       }

       private void OnDeleteTapped(object obj)
       {
        var content = obj as Vehicles;
        CollectionsList.Remove(content);
        }

      private async void OnSaveTapped(object obj)
      {
      
        profileData.Id = Id;
        profileData.name = name;
      
        if (profileData.vehicles!= null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CollectionsList.Count; i++)
            {
                profileData.vehicles[i] = 
        CollectionsList[i].VehicleNumber1;
                
            }
        }

        if (ProfileManager.UpdateProfileToDBAsync(profileData))
        { 
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", 
       "Your 
       Profile Information is updated", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("", 
    "failed", "Ok");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = 
    null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new 
     PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
    }
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code for your ListView and Entry?  The code you did post also contains a large block that is not within a method, and is therefore not valid C#.

Comment: @Jason
I have added Entry in a list view in .xaml file

Comment: @Jason that large block of code it written inside a method which is getting called in constructor and i followed this link
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZxjofHU0J0&t=223s

Comment: please read [mcve] - nobody is going to watch a youtube video in order to determine what it is you are doing.  You need to be able to provide enough detail in the body of your post in order for us to be able to help you.

Comment: @Jason 
in .xaml i have added item source , and same i am using in ViewModel Class with name as CollectionsList

Comment: are you saying that the value in Entry does not change when it is updated by the API?  Or that you cannot use the value from Entry to perform an update on the API?

Comment: @Jason  
Although i am able to display api response, Issue is- CollectionsList should also be updated with all the values but it has only latest value , bcoz of that i am not able to delete the correct data, its deleting from start. I need the updated list in order to store it in database

Comment: Where is the code where you call the API and update the data?

Comment: @Jason I have added all the code i have written in view Model

Comment: There is any Vehicle unique Id?

Comment: @AliAhmad Text="{Binding VehicleNumber1}" in .xaml and public string VehicleNumber1 { get; set; } in Model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only change your ViewModelClass like this.

```
public class ProfileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ProfileData profileData;
    public ProfileData ProfileData { get; private set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    private ObservableCollection<Vehicles> _CollectionsList;

    public ObservableCollection<Vehicles> CollectionsList
    {
        get { return _CollectionsList; }
        set
        {
            _CollectionsList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    string name;


    public string ProfileName
    {
        get => name;

        set
        {
            if (name == value)
                return;
            name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ICommand AddCommand { get; }
    public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; }

    public ProfileViewModel()
    {
        CollectionsList = new ObservableCollection<Vehicles>();

        loadProfileData();

        AddCommand = new Command(AddItems);

        DeleteCommand = new Command(OnDeleteTapped);

        SaveCommand = new Command(OnSaveTapped);

    }

    async void loadProfileData()
    {
        try
        {
            profileData = await
        ProfileManager.GetProfileDataAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("WebService:GetEventsDataAsync:Failed 
        to
        get events");
        }
        if (profileData == null)
        {
            profileData = new ProfileData();

        }

        //Loads Profile Data

        ProfileName = profileData.name;

        if (profileData.vehicles != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < profileData.vehicles.Count; i++)
            {
                Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
                vehicles.VehicleNumber1 = profileData.vehicles[i];
                CollectionsList.Add(vehicles);
            }

        }

        Id = profileData.Id;

        OnPropertyChanged("ProfileData");
    }

    private void AddItems(object obj)
    {
        Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles();
        CollectionsList.Insert(0, vehicles);
    }

    private void OnDeleteTapped(object obj)
    {
        var content = obj as Vehicles;
        CollectionsList.Remove(CollectionsList.Single(v => v.VehicleNumber1 == content.VehicleNumber1));
    }

    private async void OnSaveTapped(object obj)
    {

        profileData.Id = Id;
        profileData.name = name;

        if (profileData.vehicles != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CollectionsList.Count; i++)
            {
                profileData.vehicles[i] =
        CollectionsList[i].VehicleNumber1;

            }
        }

        if (ProfileManager.UpdateProfileToDBAsync(profileData))
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("",
       "Your 
       Profile Information is updated", "Ok");
        }
        else
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("",
    "failed", "Ok");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName =
    null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new
     PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: -I added in my delete function and SomeUniqueProperty is added in my model class, Do i need to add anything in .xaml file because its crashing throwing System.InvalidOperationException and Sequence contains more than one matching element , I debug it and content.SomeUniqueProperty is null.

Comment: @SaumyaSaloni i use SomeUniqueProperty as an example. Just replace it with your property that is unique in vehicle like id, name etc.

Comment: One more error is move this line Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles(); to inside your for loop that iterating over profileData.vehicles.

Comment: i added x:Name="DeleteList", for Entry that displays VehicleNumber n i added your code with v.DeleteList , i am getting error and a suggestion to add that property in my model.

Comment: i have two models first which has a list of vehicles --ProfileData-   public List<string> vehicles { get; set; }    --and second VehicleNumber1 
 Vehicles-  public string VehicleNumber1 { get; set; }- this  i bind in .xaml with text for Entry Text="{Binding VehicleNumber1}"

Comment: @SaumyaSaloni check it now.

Comment: -Vehicles vehicles = new Vehicles(); i added inside for loop and deletion operation is working correctly thanx

Comment: @SaumyaSaloni my pleasure. upvote the answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: for delete this will work.                                                                                       
   private void OnDeleteTapped(object obj)
           {
            var content = obj as Vehicles;
            CollectionsList.Remove(content);
            }